# Google Home - How to get Unique id for our custom analytics report

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

We are creating a custom analytics report. We need to check new user and returning user count. Currently Google Home provides a userId, but the problem is if user is not using it for more than 30 days it will delete the userId. so we need a unique deviceId. Is there any chance to get unique deviceId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: no.

**Longer answer**:

You can't get a Device ID for a few reasons:

1. Multiple users can use the same device. If you actually want to track unique users, you don't want a Device ID anyway.
2. A user can use your action from multiple devices and will be reported as the same user between all of them.
3. Even if they did, it would likely have the same limitations as for the user ID, resetting it after a period of non-use.

Use the unique user ID. Even with the ability for the user to reset it and with the 30 day non-use revocation, it provides you with an accurate enough representation of the number of unique and returning users you have that parallels the unique identification that is available on the web.

Comment: I do not really get why there is this 30 day timeout... Would be better if it were a year or two, at least. Perfectly reasonable to 'forget' after that long. But 30 days is pretty short. Some (lucky) people can go on holidays for that long...

Comment: I can't speak for Google, and they aren't likely to reply, but it could be a balance between providing utility to developers and privacy concerns that are raised by users. There are ways around this that are recently introduced that let users consent to you having their identity for longer periods.